# Accessing Box Api using Refresh token

Tags: rest, authorization, box

How can we access the Box API using the refresh token that is generated? I have followed all the steps to generate the access token and refresh token but I cannot find it anywhere how can I access the API using refresh token.

This is what I have right now:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0"
```

I am not able to do this :

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: <Refresh-Token>" "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0"
```

or

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <Refresh-Token>" "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0"
```

Any idea how we can use the Refresh token in an API call?

Answer (score 3):

The access_token is used to make Box Content API calls.

The refresh_token is used to obtain a new access_token & refresh_token pair since access_tokens expire in around 60 minutes.

```
curl https://api.box.com/oauth2/token 
-d 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
-d 'refresh_token=<MY_REFRESH_TOKEN>' \
-d 'client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>' \
-d 'client_secret=<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>' \
-X POST
```

Comment: The access token obtained from refresh_token also has the expiration of 60 minutes?

Comment: Yes.  The access_token always expires around 60 minutes.